# How to create SecurityBindingElement in Dot net core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to use wcf soap service in dot net core web api project. since dot net core don't support configuration via web.config file. all wcf configuration i have to do in code only but i am not able to find equivalent code in dot net core 2.1 for below config

```
<customBinding>
   <binding name="SecureBinding">
  <security includeTimestamp="false"  
   authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" />
   <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
   maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
   maxNameTableCharCount="16384000" />
   </textMessageEncoding>
  <httpsTransport  maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" requireClientCertificate="true"/>
</binding>
```

equivalent code in dot net core written so far is

```
 var messegeElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
        {
            MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap11),
            ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
            {
                MaxDepth = 128,
                MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue,
                MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue,
                MaxBytesPerRead = 4096,
                MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384000,

            }
        };

        HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement
        {
            MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
            RequireClientCertificate = true,
            AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm,
            TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered
        };

        CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding(messegeElement, httpsTransport);
```

how to write security element like

```
 SecurityBindingElement sbe = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
 sbe.IncludeTimestamp = false;
```

i have searched but found that SecurityBindingElement is not available in dot net core yet. if there any workaround to this?

Comment: According to this you can use the Configuration API to read from a config file in .Net Core 2.1 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration).

Comment: I had the same problem and ended up writing a proxy in NodeJs with wcf.js, because I needed it to run on a Linux host.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf